# Create a web service in intel XDK with http header

Tags: jquery, json, http-headers, intel-xdk

I want to crate a custom service in intel XDK that can get JSON data from remote server. But the API need to add http header whenever it GET JSON data.

The http header look like this

```
login = base64(username+password)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user xhr.setRequestHeader("headername",haeader value);

code

```
credentials64=Base64.encode(params.userID+":"+params.password);

$.ajax({url: url,beforeSend: function( xhr ) {xhr.setRequestHeader("credentials",credentials64)}, type: 'GET'});
```